# Передача переменной с класса в другой класс [php]

Tags: php

есть контроллер страницы профиля

```
class Profile extends Controller {

    public function index() {

        global $twig;

        return  $data = [
            'title' => $username,
            'content' => $twig->render('profile.twig')
        ];
    }
}
```

И класс загрузки этого файла либо другого, в зависимости от адреса

```
class Core {
    protected $currentController = 'Home';
    protected $currentMethod = 'index';
    protected $params = [];

    public function __construct() {

        global $twig, $dataBase;

        // Get URL
        $url = $this->getUrl();

        // Look in BLL for first value
        if ($url) {

            $username = strtolower($url[0]);
            $userInfo = $dataBase->super_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = '{$username}'");

            if($userInfo == true){
                if (file_exists('../app/controllers/Profile.php')) {
                    // If exists, set as controller
                    $this->currentController = ucwords('profile');
                    // Unset 0 Index
                    unset($url[0]);
                }
            } else {
                if (file_exists('../app/controllers/' . ucwords($url[0]) . '.php')) {
                    // If exists, set as controller
                    $this->currentController = ucwords($url[0]);
                    // Unset 0 Index
                    unset($url[0]);
                }
            }
        }

        // Require the controller
        require_once '../app/controllers/' . $this->currentController . '.php';

        // Instantiate controller class
        $this->currentController = new $this->currentController;

        // Check for second part of url
        if (isset($url[1])) {
            // Check to see if method exists in controller
            if (method_exists($this->currentController, $url[1])) {
                $this->currentMethod = $url[1];
                // Unset 1 index
                unset($url[1]);
            }
        }

        // Get params
        $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];

        // Call a callback with array of params
        $return = call_user_func_array([$this->currentController, $this->currentMethod], $this->params);

        // Load Base Template
        echo $twig->render('index.twig', [
            'title' => $return['title'],
            'content' => $return['content']
        ]);
    }

    public function getUrl() {
        if (isset($_GET['plugin'])) {
            $url = rtrim($_GET['plugin'], '/');
            $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
            $url = explode('/', $url);

            return $url;
        }
    }
}
```

Адрес открытый в адресной строке "/username". Я сделал проверку, если есть пользователь с именем **username**, то грузим контроллер профиля, все хорошо грузится работает как положено, но мне еще нужно отправить переменную из класса **Core** в контроллер **Profile** с данными переменной **$username**. Помогите реализовать.

Прошу не унижать сразу, я новичок в php..

Comment: $this->params['username'] = $username

Comment: Вот так `$this->currentController = new $this->currentController;` делать не стоит, создайте для имени класса отдельную переменную.

Comment: `$username = strtolower($url[0]);`
А если в базе юзер записан большими буквами?

Comment: Всегда проверяйте входные данные. Надеяться на FILTER_SANITIZE_URL не стоит. Если у $dataBase нет соответствующей функции, тогда через регулярные выражения.

Comment: @fixer ,
$this->params['username'] = $username, а как в контроллере Profile принять эти данные?

Comment: Сорри, пропустил: `public function index($username)`

Comment: @fixer огромное вам спасибо! Ваш коммент дал мне толчок. Сделал так: $url[] = $getUsername;, все заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @fixer

Сделал так, заменил:

```
if($userInfo == true){
.........
```

на:

```
if($userInfo == true){
   $url[] = $getUsername
.........
```

Строку

```
public function index()
```

заменил на

```
public function index($username)
```

Все заработало